# OSM android does not show map tile

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have implemented a app using Open Street Map and I used OSM android as a library for that. I worked well before but I run the app lately, it did not display map tile at all. I changed tile provider several times but it did not work.

Here is my code:

```
public class OsmMapActivity extends SherlockActivity {

protected MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutId());

        initialiseMap();
    }

    protected void initialiseMap(){
        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);                        
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM); //Mapink and other providers do not work
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    }
}
```

In additional, does OSM android support third party provider? I have my own OSM tile server and it works well when I display map using Javascript but it does not work in Android code.

```
OnlineTileSourceBase tileSource = new XYTileSource("MyOSM", null, 1, 19, 256, ".png", new String[]{"http://tactile.myserver.com/osm_tiles"});
TileSourceFactory.addTileSource(tileSource);
mapView.setTileSource("MyOSM");
```

Your answer would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:
I'm using 
osmdroid-android-4.2.jar
Android 4.0.3

When I see it more closely, I could see the map tile very short time and then another layer overrides on it. I removed other layers except base layer from the map but nothing changed.

Comment: Try to figure out which URLs it tries to retrieve. Then check if they are valid and return tile images.

Comment: Debug the requests it make to the server

Comment: Specify Android SDK and osmdroid versions used.

Comment: did you set the manifest permissions? what is the target api set at?

Answer (score 0):

```
    MapController mapController;
    MapView map = (MapView) root.findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapController = map.getController();
    myLocationoverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(map);
    myLocationoverlay.setEnabled(true);
    map.getOverlays().add(myLocationoverlay);
    mapController.setZoom(9.5);
    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(35.744198, 51.4285752);
    mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
```